# Extreme floating point precision number 1.0-(0.1^200) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, precision

I was creating a threshold with extreme floating point precision. I am in need of a value something like 0.999999999... with 200 9s. Is that possible in python?

One solution I thought of was to create it using 1.-1e-200, but that just gives me the value 1.

Comment: AFAIK you can use the `decimal` module for this purpose. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Another option is [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The standard `fractions.Fraction` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) provides unlimited-precision exact rational arithmetic.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> x = Fraction(1) - Fraction(1, 10**200)
```

[`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) might also suit your needs if you're looking for high-precision rather than exact arithmetic, but you'll have to tweak the context settings to allow more than the default 28 significant digits.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, Context
>>> decimal.setcontext(Context(prec=1000))
>>> x = Decimal(1) - 1 / Decimal(10**200)
```

Comment: Thanks, Fraction works well for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with normal variables.  Python uses the processor's double precision floating point numbers, which hold about 17 decimal digits.

There are add-on packages like `bigfloat` that can do arbitrary floating point arithmetic, but you'd need a pretty good reason to use them.  Most people overestimate the need for precision in floating point math.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tim. This really helps.

Comment: Re “Python uses the processor's double precision floating point numbers, which hold about 17 decimal digits”: The Python documentation does not specify how Python implementations implement floating-point arithmetic, either what precision they must provide, what format they must use, or whether they use the processor’s floating-point instructions or something else. The format commonly used as “double precision” does not “hold” about 17 decimal digits. Its information content is equivalent to a little under 16 decimal digits.

Comment: Your comment is useless.  54 bits of mantissa provides 16.7 decimal digits.  If that's not "about 17", then maybe you need a new definition.  Whether the spec is specific or not, every Python implementation that exists today uses the IEEE-754 doubles provided by the hardware.  I stand by my answer.

Comment: @Tim Roberts.  Doubles have a mantissa of 52 binary digits, and a significand of 53, so the nominal number of decimal digits of precision is log(2^53) ~= 15.95.  I do agree that VIRTUALLY all implementations use doubles, AND the python specs do not spec it (if I am wrong, please cite your reference)--so you are "both right" :-)

Comment: As an aside, I recall reading one of Knuth's books where he proved that 0.999... == 1.000...